# AWS CDK - How to setup Cognito User Pool with "Authorization Code" flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I'm currently trying to create an Amazon Cognito User Pool with OAuth flow "*Authorization Code*" via the AWS CDK as described in the documentation [aws-cognito module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cognito-readme.html).

Here is the typescript code of my stack:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { UserPool, VerificationEmailStyle, OAuthScope } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cognito';
import { Duration } from '@aws-cdk/core';

export class UserPoolStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const userPool = new UserPool(this, 'stackoverflow-userpool', {
            userPoolName: 'stackoverflow-userpool',
            selfSignUpEnabled: true,
            signInCaseSensitive: false,
            userVerification: {
                emailSubject: 'Verify your email!',
                emailBody: 'Hello, Thanks for signing up! {##Verify Email##}',
                emailStyle: VerificationEmailStyle.LINK
            },
            signInAliases: {
                username: true,
                email: true
            },
            requiredAttributes: {
                email: true
            },
            passwordPolicy: {
                minLength: 12,
                requireLowercase: true,
                requireUppercase: true,
                requireDigits: true,
                requireSymbols: true,
                tempPasswordValidity: Duration.days(7)
            }
        });

        const client = userPool.addClient('stackoverflow-userpool-localhost-client', {
            userPoolClientName: 'stackoverflow-localhost-client',
            oAuth: {
                flows: { authorizationCodeGrant: true },
                scopes: [OAuthScope.OPENID],
                callbackUrls: ['http://localhost:4200/callback']
            }
        });

        userPool.addDomain('stackoverflow-userpool-domain-prefix', {
            cognitoDomain: {
                domainPrefix: 'stackoverflow'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For whatever reason my "Cognito User Pool" is not enabled as an "Identity Provider" in my "App client". (see screenshot)
[image: App Client with not Enabled Identity Provider]

Is my configuration wrong? I can't find any property that would enable this.

Is it a bug or because the module is still experimental? What confuses me is why would they describe how to set up the "Authorization Code" flow in the documentation if it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

at the present date, looks good and worked for me. Maybe an old version of aws-cdk? In any case, you can e[xplicitly enable Cognito User Pool on the client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cognito-readme.html#app-clients)

```
        const client = userPool.addClient('stackoverflow-userpool-localhost-client', {
            userPoolClientName: 'stackoverflow-localhost-client',
            oAuth: {
                flows: { authorizationCodeGrant: true },
                scopes: [OAuthScope.OPENID],
                callbackUrls: ['http://localhost:4200/callback']
            },
            supportedIdentityProviders: [
                UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.AMAZON,
                UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.COGNITO,
            ]
        });
```